# Linked lists sharing tails?

Tags: c++11, singly-linked-list

Is there a library implementation or way to define singly linked lists in C++ that have a common tail from some element onwards? I'd like to be able to append a linked list to another, so that appending would just equal changing the final next pointer of one of the lists to point to the head of the other. Similarly, I would like be able to prepend an element to a list returning a new list where the head is just one step before the head of the other.

This would allow me to trivially get memory consumption down to linear from quadratic in a piece of code that I have... I.e. use the standard way of handling lists that all functional languages internally do.

Comment: Trivial to do on your own, but not supported/allowed by `std::list` or `std::slist`.

Comment: Thanks, that was all I needed to know. It's easy to implement from scratch however.